# Question on supremum of a sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $k$ and $u$ be positive integers. Let $a_{k,u}$ be positive real numbers such that for each fixed $k$, $$a_{k,u}\rightarrow 0 \text { as } u \rightarrow \infty.$$ Moreover assume that for each fixed $u$,
$$k^ma_{k,u} \rightarrow 0\text { as } k \rightarrow \infty,$$

where $m$ is a fixed positive integer.

Does it implies that $$\sup_{k}(k^ma_{k,u}) \rightarrow 0\text { as } u \rightarrow \infty?$$

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: $a_{k,u}\to 0$ when what goes to what? If $a_{k,u}=\frac{1}{(k+1)(u+1)}$, it is not even true that $k^m a_{k,u}\to 0$ when $k\to +\infty$.

Comment: Have a lok at $a_{k,u}=\frac{k}{u+1}$

Comment: I modified the question slightly to prevent examples given by Eitzen and Aurizio in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $a_{u,u}=1$, and $a_{k,u}=2^{-u-k}$ when $k\neq u$.
Then we see that $\sup_k({k^ma_{k,u}})=u^m$ for every $u$.

Comment: This is not a counterexample because in the question $a_{k,u}$ is assumed to be positive (I did not say that they are non-negative) real numbers. You cannot make them zero.

Comment: @MathStudent Corrected. Please see.